# Google Directions OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: google-directions-api

I am having a few issues with Google Directions API.
I am receiving an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error every time when I can see from the Google Console that is only a couple of queries in the last 24 hours, and I have definitely not gone over my allowance.  Directions API is enabled.

I have billing setup although I am on the free trial apparently I still have over £200 of credit.

This was working fine and now for some reason, it just stopped working.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, my credit card has expired on Google.  Didn't think to check there as I was using the free trial!